# how do i resolve the issue of no reverse match found?

Tags: python-3.x, url, django-views, django-templates

> django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Rever\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 694, in _reverse
> se for 'user_login' not found. 'user_login'
> is not a valid view function or pattern name

I think the main problem is at the URL mapping as i am really new to this, I am just practicing by watching video lectures and that guy is using some older version of django and the URL mapping used by that guy involves resular expressions i.e ^ and $ sign. He has put dollar sign at the end of a url link for the first time and i can not find any alternate of that in django 3+ as i am using Path function for the mapping instead of regular expressions.

Views.py

```
def user_login(request):

if request.method == 'POST':
    username = request.POST.get('username')
    password = request.POST.get('password')

    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

    if user:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))

        else:
            return HttpResponse("Account not Active")

    else:
        print("Someone tried to login and failed")
        print("Username: {} and Password {}".format(username, 
password))
        return HttpResponse("invalid login details supplied!")

else:

    return render(request, 'basicapp/login.html',{})
```

urls.py from basicapp

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.urls import path
from basicapp import views



 app_name = 'basicapp'

urlpatterns = [
    path('register/', views.register, name= 'register'),
    path('user_login/', views.user_login, name= 'login'),
]
```

urls.py from project

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from basicapp import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path ('',views.index, name ='index'),
    path ('basicapp/', include('basicapp.urls')),
    path ('logout/', views.user_logout, name='logout'),
    path ('special/', views.special, name = 'special'),
]
```

base template call

```
      <div class="container">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a class='navbar-brand' href="{% url 'index' %}">DJANGO</a></li>
      <li><a class="navbar-link " href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">Admin</a></li>
      <li><a class="navbar-link"  href="{% url 'basicapp:register' %}">Register</a></li>

      {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <li><a class='navbar-link' href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a></li>
      {% else %}
        <li><a class="navbar-link" href="{% url 'basicapp:user_login' %}">Login</a></li>
      {% endif %}
```

Comment: Please include the code using code blocks ``` not screenshots

Comment: kindly look at it now

Answer (score 0):

Import **reverse_lazy** and try replacing

```
reverse('index')
```

With

```
reverse_lazy('index')
```

Comment: i did resolve this issue, Thank you. but what actually worked for me was to change the name in the URL pattern list referring to user_login, 
urlpatterns = [
    path('register/', views.register, name= 'register'),
    path('user_login/', views.user_login, name= 'user_login'),
]